# Experiencing high fever

Tags: present-continuous

How can I express the idea "Now I am experiencing high fever" in response to an enquiry?

Comment: In relaxed conversational contexts, you ***have** a [high] fever*.

Answer (score 3):

The usual form of verb to use when telling of an illness or condition is the simple present. You would say "I have a high fever", or more casually, "I have got a high fever".

[Have and have got](https://www.eslbase.com/grammar/have-got)

Comment: Feverish us a generic term. It doesn’t refer to high fever specifically.